# What is .symbol files in IPA

Tags: ios, crash-reports, ipa, symbolicatecrash

I've IPA which is uploaded on AppStore. On unzipping IPA I see two folders 
Payload and Symbols.

Symbols folder contains many files with extension .symbol

[image]

Any idea what would be these symbol files? Can we use them for symbolication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is [debug symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_symbol). They contain a mapping between encoded names and locations in your compiled code and the original function names among other debug information. Each `<UUID>.symbols` file represents either the main binary of you app or a framework that your app is using. You can find out which is which using mdfind ([see example](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#finding-local-dsyms)).

[See this about symbolication](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-SYMBOLICATE_WITH_ATOS)